# JQuery UI tabs beforeLoad method with JSON

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, jquery-ui-tabs

I try to load dynamically content of tab. Source is ASP.NET method decorated by [WebMethod] attribute.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Result()
{
   return RenderControl("WebUserControl1.ascx");
}
```

It works fine when the tab is loaded by this code:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Dynamic User Control</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
</div>

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebForm1.aspx/Result", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#tabs-1').html(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (msg){ 
        $('#tabs-1').html('Cannot load');
    }
});
```

But when the tabs are defined differently:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx/Result">Dynamic user Control</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this call loads whole page content and put it into the tab. Therefore I tried to change data type to json but then whole tab load fail somewhere inside ajax call.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({

    beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
        ui.ajaxSettings.accepts = { json: "application/json, text/javascript" };
        ui.ajaxSettings.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        ui.ajaxSettings.type = "POST";
        ui.ajaxSettings.dataTypes[0] = "json";

        ui.jqXHR.error = function () {
            $('#tabs-3').html('Cannot load');
        }
    },
});
```

Checked what headers are sent with the request and these modifications to ajaxSettings are not sent to server at all.

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Version of JQuery-UI used is 1.10.0.
Version of JQuery used is 1.9.0.

Edit: Checked in Firebug that Content-Type header is not set as per ajaxSettings to application/json. Therefore web page responded with text/html response. Confirmed that if the request header is forced to json (by live headers firefox addon) then json reponse is returned. Is there any way to force tabs to pass correct http headers?

Comment: Have you tried using `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` (in addition to WebMethod attribute)? Else, asp.net won't expect data in JSON format...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have added the attribute but it doesn't help because the ajax call is done with wrong headers. If there are correct request headers then asp.net page returns json response correctly. That is why the first approach work.

Answer (score 0):

UI tabs `beforeLoad` method is basically the Ajax `beforeSend` function. For your particular problem you've to do something like this

```
ui.jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript");
ui.ajaxSettings.type = "POST";
ui.ajaxSettings.dataTypes[0] = "json";
```

This will change the accept header of request.